# ASP.NET-Parser error: invalid format of 3d party DLL

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I am getting an error which I do not understand - despite the many words being used in the message ;-(

I'm running in german windows, so I have translated some of the msg *(in italics after the text)*

The file is valid - I have copied the entire directory-structure from a working project which also used that DLL. So it might be that some path-info is wrong somewhere etc.

Serverfehler in der Anwendung '/refdb'.
Parserfehler  *Parser error*
Beschreibung: Beim Verarbeiten einer Resource, die für diese Anforderung erforderlich ist, ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Überprüfen Sie folgende Fehlerinformationen und ändern Sie die Quelldatei entsprechend.

Parser-Fehlermeldung: Das Format der Datei 'PeterBlum.DES' ist ungültig. *Invalid fileformat of PeterBlum.DES*

Quellfehler:

Zeile 1:  <%@ Register tagPrefix="des" assembly="PeterBlum.DES" namespace="PeterBlum.DES" %>
Zeile 2:  <%@ Register tagPrefix="despval" assembly="PeterBlum.DES.NativeToDES" namespace="PeterBlum.DES.NativeToDES" %>
Zeile 3:  <%@Page Language="apl" Debug="true" Inherits="COPA" src="COPA_MS.dws" %>

Quelldatei: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ciwrefdb\refdb01.aspx    Zeile: 1

Überwachung beim Laden der Assembly: Mit folgenden Informationen kann bestimmt werden, warum die Assembly 'PeterBlum.DES' nicht geladen werden konnte.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = PeterBlum.DES
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/ciwrefdb
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = bin

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Post-policy reference: PeterBlum.DES
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v1.1.4322/Temporary ASP.NET Files/refdb/e4095c5f/e6e8b1fa/PeterBlum.DES.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v1.1.4322/Temporary ASP.NET Files/refdb/e4095c5f/e6e8b1fa/PeterBlum.DES/PeterBlum.DES.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/ciwrefdb/bin/PeterBlum.DES.DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, after some googling I tried to move a "location path"-entry in web.config right to the start and that fixed this problem. I'm happy that it works and puzzled that this could have caused that...